# How to extract information (citation, h-index, currently working institution etc) about all professors in a specific field from Google scholar?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to compare different information (citation, h-index, etc) of professors in a specific field in different institutions all over the world by data mining and analysis techniques. But I have no idea how to extract these data of hundreds of (or even thousands of) professors since Google does not provide an official API for it. So I am wondering are there any other ways to do that?

Comment: My question is, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @DDPWNAGE Because today I happened to talk with a physics graduate student about this problem. Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Sounds somewhat interesting. I don't know Python too well. Good luck with it!

Comment: How will you know which authors are professors?

Comment: @Scott Professors are usually listed as the corresponding author in the last place.

Comment: [Github code](https://github.com/pjotrp/bioruby-bioinformatics-impact/blob/master/js/citations-gadget/citGadget.js) already exists for  Ruby - to avoid breeching google TOS you can calculate results on demand only or use a batch job with time delays. Alternatively find the top 20 or so and calculate for those only, or limit the frequency of your requests (max 1 per second)  and email the user when the data is ready or suggest they check back in 30 mins etc. You could also store previous calculations with the date calculated displaying - h-index does not change much weekly/monthly.

Comment: @Mousey batch jobs with delays **do breach the TOS**.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse you have not given a source for this here or in your answer as suggested by SO. The TOS don't refer to batch jobs with or without delay.

Comment: @Mousey "try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide". Scraping is such an "other method".

Answer (score -1):

Use this [google code tool](http://code.google.com/p/citations-gadget/) will calculate an individual h-index but if you do this on demand for a limited number in a particular field you will not break the [terms of use](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/) - it doesn't specifically refer to limits on access but does refer to disruption of service (eg bulk requests may potentially do this) the [export](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/help.html#export) questions state:

**I wrote a program to download lots of search results, but you blocked my computer from accessing Google Scholar. Can you raise the limit?**
    Err, no, please respect our robots.txt when you access Google Scholar using automated software. As the wearers of crawler's shoes and webmaster's hat, we cannot recommend adherence to web standards highly enough.

Web of Science does have an API available and a [collaboration agreement with google scholar](http://wokinfo.com/googlescholar/)  but Web of Science only for [certain individuals](http://wokinfo.com/products_tools/products/related/webservices/ws_faq/)

A solution could be to request user's web of science credential (or your own) to return the information on demand - perhaps for the top ones in the field, then store it as you planned. Google scholar only updates a few times per week and this would not be excessive use.

The other option is to **request permission** from google, which is an mentioned in the terms of use, although seems unlikely to be granted.

Comment: I doubt that this is permitted usage: "try to access them using a method other than the interface and the instructions that we provide"

Comment: I think you may be misinterpreting the wording - they are referring to using another method to access the same information on *their servers*,  for example knowingly circumvents their restrictions. I actually said to use their link up with Web of Science - which may or may not directly access google at the tme of the request, it seems likely to accesses the google scholar information Web of Science stores. That access depends on Web of Science's policy, not google's. 
I also suggested to **request permission** which is in their terms and presumably others eg Web of Science have done so.

Comment: That is the terminology they use for anything that is not a regular web browser. They don't offer an API, they don't offer exceptions. It's their company policy.

Answer (score -1):

I've done a [project](https://github.com/vignif/Crawler-google-scholar) exactly on this.

You provide an input text file to the script with the names of the professor you'd like to retrieve the information from, and the script is able to crawl google scholar and manage the info you are interested on.

The project provides also a functionality for downloading automatically the profile picture of the researchers/professors.

In order to respect the constraint imposed by the portal you can set a delay between each requests. if you have >1k of profile to crawl it might take a while but it works.

A concurrency-enabled script has also been implemented and it runs way faster than the basic sequence approach.

note: in order to specify the information you need you have to know either the id of the class of the html generated by google scholar or the name of the class.

good luck!